# Track changes of an object contained in a Dictionary<TKey, TValue> and change its TKey accordingly

Tags: c#, vb.net, dictionary, inotifypropertychanged

I am writing a class library to interact with a domain Active Directory. In my object model, I have the following:

1. Domain;
2. Organizational Unit;
3. Group;
4. User.

In my `Domain` object, I have an `Entries` property and an Add() method.

```
public class Domain {
    // The ReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue> is a custom wrapper over an IDictionary.
    public ReadOnlyDictionary<string, IDirectoryEntry> Entries { get; }

    public void Add(IDirectoryEntry entry) {
        Entries.Add(entry.Name, entry);
    }
}
```

Now, let's suppose I have the following code testing for changes.

```
[Test()]
public void ChangeTesting {
    Domain domain = new Domain("LDAP://...");
    Group g = new Group("groupName");

    domain.Add(g);

    g.Name = "ChangedName";

    Assert.IsTrue(domain.ContainsKey("ChangedName"));
}
```

For your information, I implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to ease my life, but I don't seem to find a way to make it work the way I want. Perhaps am I not doing things right somehow, as for the location of different methods, I don't know.

**How can I make my `Domain` aware of a change that occured within one of its `Entries`, so that the `TKey` value is also changed?**

That is wanted because one could possibly add an entry, change its name meanwhile adding a new entry with the "old" name of the actual within entry, and cause a conflict, etc. In the end, causing the test to fail. But I'd like to make it pass like it actually is.

Is there another better approach or workaround?

Comment: I think that the simplest workaround will be to remove and add an item again.

Comment: That is also what I came up with while thinking of it. The key is to keep it as simple as possible for the user, but in the end it is no better to give ourselves much trouble! =) Thanks for your opinion! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **really** bad hack, and it will probably fail miserably in a multithreaded environment, but here goes:

```
private Dictionary<IDirectoryEntry, PropertyChangedEventHandler> eventHandlers =
    new Dictionary<IDirectoryEntry, PropertyChangedEventHandler>();

public void Add(IDirectoryEntry entry) {
    string oldName = entry.Name;

    PropertyChangedEventHandler h;
    h = (o, args) => {
        if (args.PropertyName == "Name" &&
                entry.Name != oldName &&
                Entries[oldName] == entry) {
            entry.PropertyChanged -= h;
            Entries.Remove(oldName);
            Add(entry);
        }
    };

    eventHandlers[entry] = h;
    entry.PropertyChanged += h;

    Entries.Add(entry.Name, entry);
}

public void Remove(IDirectoryEntry entry) {
    if (Entries[entry.Name] == entry) {
        Entries.Remove(entry.Name);
        eventHandlers.Remove(entry);
    }
}
```

You will probably want to `lock` on something for each handler **AND** inside the anonymous method if you expect concurrent activity.  (This could mean removing an entry from one thread and changing the name of an entry from another!)

Comment: Thanks! And yes, there will be a `Remove` method, in case the user no longer wants the entry added to his domain. In the end, it ends up with removing from and adding to the same dictionary.

Comment: Updated.  Please note the comment I added at the end -- multithreaded access will kill this code if you don't modify it to lock properly.

Comment: And when you say "this is a **really** bad hack", I understand it is far from a good practice/approach, and this could lead to flaws later on, won't it? Am I overcomplicating things here, in your humble point of view, for such a little gain for the library end-user? Had I better go with a "do-it-yourself" approach as for the entries in the domain object?

Comment: @cdhowie: `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` itself is non-thread-safe.  You're not losing anything.

Comment: @SLaks: Of course, I'm not indicating that my hack is less thread-safe than the original code, only that neither are thread-safe (at least it looks that way from the trimmed code that the Will posted).

Comment: @Will: That's entirely up to you and your needs.  As long as developers using your library know what to expect, it's not necessarily bad.  However, I would definitely test the crap out of this new behavior in some test cases to ensure that it's working like you expect.

Comment: @cdhowie: Thanks for your kind help and this provided solution! I shall try it and let you know whether it works as expected. =)